# If value equals null, I didn't want to add field on firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

If value equals null, I didn't want to add field.

I tried, but not working below way,

```
return _db.collection('users').document(uid).setData({
  'businessDetails': {
    model.inShop != null ? 'inShop' : 'Y': null,
    model.inShopAndClientLocation != null ? 'inShopAndClientLocation' : 'Y': null,
    model.clientLocation != null ? 'clientLocation' : 'Y': null,
  }
}, merge: true).catchError((e){
  print('Error is $e');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use collection-if:

```dart
  'businessDetails': {
    if (model.inShop != null)
      'inShop': 'Y',
    if (model.inShopAndClientLocation != null)
      'inShopAndClientLocation': 'Y',
    if (model.clientLocation != null)
      'clientLocation': 'Y',
  }
```